# Mongo/Morphia StackOverflow error?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity("platform_defs")
class PlatformDef {
    @Id
    Long id

    @Property("name")
    String name

    @Property("abbreviation")
    String abbreviation

    @Property("type")
    String type

    @Property("hg_repo")
    String hgRepo

    @Property("port")
    Long port

    @Property("status")
    String status
}
```

And the following Morphia code trying to persist an instance of that entity:

```
public void savePlatformDef(PlatformDef pDef) {
    try {
        AppConfig config = getConfig();
        String dbName = config.getMongo().getDatabaseName();
        Mongo mongo = new Mongo(config.getMongo().getHost(), config.getMongo().getPort());
        morphia = new Morphia();
        datastore = morphia.createDatastore(mongo, dbName);
        morphia.map(PlatformDef.class);
        datastore.save(pDef);
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I run this I get:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Here is the recursive list of calls being made:

```
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper(toDBObject:40)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper(writeMappedField:642)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper(toDBObject:544)
at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper(toDBObject:526)
```

This pattern repeats over and over again...
What's wrong with my setup?

Comment: You'll need to post more than just the top line of the stack trace. Usually StackOverflowErrors are down to an infinite (or very long) loop of recursive method calls. The trace itself should tell you if that's the case if you keep seeing a repeating pattern of method calls.

Comment: You need to post either the whole stack trace, or at least point to the line in your own code that it refers to.  This stack overflow often happens when you have an object which contains another object that points back to the original object.  In your code, you only use simple types (longs and strings) - is this really the full code of the class you're trying to persist?

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late to help you, but I ran into this issue as well.  I can't tell from what you provided code wise, but most likely your using an anonymous inner class at some point in the construction of the platformDef you pass to your savePlatformDef method.  Apparently morphia does not support anonymous inner classes, they are known to cause stack overflows just like this.  See this bug for detail:

https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues/402

Hopefully this answer will help others like me in the future :)

Answer (score -1):

1. Use an ObjectId for your `@Id`
2. You don't need to annotate attributes if you don't require a different name than the one from the variable
3. Use `MongoClient` instead of `Mongo`, which is deprecated / already removed depending on your version of Mongo Java driver
4. Why are you opening a new database connection for every save operation? This is pretty expensive and unnecessary, since the Java driver will automatically pool them for you